# Make a reuqest using NUSOAP with PHP

Tags: php

So I've been banging my head against the wall on this , I need to make a request to a wsdl site, proivde the username and password and call a function "getVehicleDetails" on the site http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl , I have to use NuSOAP for this. I've tried

```
<?php  

require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$proxyhost = isset($_POST['proxyhost']) ? $_POST['proxyhost'] : '';
$proxyport = isset($_POST['proxyport']) ? $_POST['proxyport'] : '';

$proxyusername = isset($_POST['proxyusername']) ? $_POST['theusername'] : '';
$proxypassword = isset($_POST['proxypassword']) ? $_POST['thepassword'] : '';

$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl', 'wsdl',
                        $proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);

                        $err = $client->getError();

                        if ($err) {

                            echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';

                        }

// Doc/lit parameters get wrapped

$param = array('Symbol' => 'IBM');

$result = $client->call('getVehicleDetails', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
// Check for a fault

if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';

} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}
echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';



?>
```

But all I get is an error that states
"no transport found, or selected transport is not yet supported!"

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Using plain SOAP I get $client = new SoapClient('http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl');
 
$params = array();

 $params["username"] = 'spwf87';
 $params["password"] = 'hk8*9jd';

 $result = $client->getVehicleDetails($params); 

 print_r($result); , This simply results in Correct Credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an error in the returned information for some reason there was a '!' which messed up everything, I had to capture the info and remove that character before successfully pulling in info. The error was mainly due to the response from the server being poorly written.